# Active Directory Domain User to be used to run Windows service

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts, accounts

I have an Active Directory containing domain users for all employees that are used for computer login, file server permission, access control RDP, etc...

Also, I have more than one service that running as a Windows service and IIS Pools, and these services need to be run with domain user, so how can create a domain user will just be used to run specific service only without other functionality like computer login.

Answer (score 1):

Those are called service accounts. You create a user account, give it a very strong password and give it a necessary privileges. But it is better to use [MSA accounts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/service-accounts-standalone-managed) for better security.